# QGIS Uploading images or files for features

Tags: qgis, image, files

I am using a QGIS 2.12 project and I would like to know if it is possible to upload files and photos for each element in a layer.

The files should be stored for example in C:\myproject\files

I can't think of any feature in QGIS right now that could achieve this..

The idea is to use it in a microsoft Surface tablet, so that users can take a picture of a feature with the camera (of a streetlight, a bench..) and assign it to the feature.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where do you want to uploade to?

Comment: to any folder in the computer, for example, to C:\myproject\files... it is not a real upload then, just a copy/paste to a folder and rename (with the id of the feature or whatever). The idea is to use it in a microsft Surface tablet, so that users can take a picture of a feature (streetlight for example) and assign it to the feature